# running options for VLC in terminal

Tags: macos, command-line, terminal, vlc-media-player

I'm following a tutorial where the person does:

```
vlc /Users/darren/Downloads/movie.mkv –video-filter=scene –scene-format=jpg –scene-prefix=movie –scene-ratio=150 –scene-height=1080 –scene-width=1920
```

im trying to do the same, but replacing the beginning "vlc" with /Applications/VLC.app/Contents/MacOS/VLC and of course using my own movie file path.

I get a bunch of errors.

EDIT:

I tried this

```
/Applications/VLC.app/Contents/MacOS/VLC /Users/me/Downloads/complete/movie/sample.mkv --scene-format=jpg --scene-prefix=movie --scene-ratio=150 --scene-height=1080 --scene-width=1920 --scene-path=/Users/me/Downloads/complete/movie
```

and I get

```
[0x100214a88] main libvlc: Running vlc with the default interface. Use 'cvlc' to use vlc without interface.
 m_el[mi_level] == NULL
 arrrrrrrrrrrrrg Up cannot escape itself
 m_el[mi_level] == NULL
 arrrrrrrrrrrrrg Up cannot escape itself
 m_el[mi_level] == NULL
 arrrrrrrrrrrrrg Up cannot escape itself
[0x102018908] dts decoder: DTS channels:6 samplerate:48000 bitrate:1536000
[0x101351e78] auhal audio output error: You should configure your speaker layout with Audio Midi Setup Utility in /Applications/Utilities. Now using Stereo mode.
Stream with high frequencies VQ coding
```

Comment: show us the errors

Comment: Basically what it says: You need `cvlc`, the command line version. IIRC isn't there in the downloadable app, you'd rather have to [build it yourself](http://wiki.videolan.org/OSXCompile) using the [source](http://sourceforge.net/projects/vlc/files/1.1.9/vlc-1.1.9.tar.bz2/download), which gives you the `cvlc` binary. But which tutorial are you following and do you *really* need VLC for that? Are you trying to convert a movie into JPGs?

Comment: i was thinking there might be an easier way. I just want to take screen shots of movie every 150 frames or whatever I specify.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `ffmpeg` to extract thumbnails for your video:

```
ffmpeg -i video.mp4 -r 1 image-%4d.jpg
```

where:

- `-i <input-file>` reads from the input file
- `-r <fps>` forces an output of `fps` frame per second
- `image-%4d.jpg` meaning the output files are named `image-0001.jpg`, ... and so on, where `%xd` means `x` digits are used to create the output names.

---

**How to get ffmpeg on OS X:**

You can get an older version of `ffmpeg` by downloading [FFmpegX](http://www.ffmpegx.com/) and then using the following instead of `ffmpeg <options>`:

```
/Applications/ffmpegX.app/Contents/Resources/ffmpeg <options>
```

To simplify this, you can do a

```
ln -s /Applications/ffmpegX.app/Contents/Resources/ffmpeg /usr/local/bin/ffmpeg
```

in order to be able to run the short command from everywhere.

---

Alternatively you can get the latest version of `ffmpeg` by [installing Homebrew](https://github.com/mxcl/homebrew) and then running

```
brew install ffmpeg
```

Comment: setting up ffmpeg seems just as complicated?

Comment: I updated my answer, take the `ffmpegx` option, that way you'll only have to download the app.

Comment: Let me know if it works out, otherwise we can find a way around. I just tested it with `ffmpegx` and had no problems.

Comment: cool i setup ffmpeg... not ffmpegx. is there anyway to get less screens like every 150 frames? Can you also set the quality? Right now the screens are pixelated in some cases

Comment: I meant `ffmpeg`, sorry. Control it over the `-r` parameter, it is the target frame rate. You could use `-r 0.1` to get one thumbnail for every ten seconds of video, for example. The quality will always be the best. The pixelation probably comes from the video itself. You can try outputting to a `png` instead of `jpg` but I could not spot the difference.

Comment: the quality may be because of my video file... for -r i guess i can use 0.5 if I want less screenshots.

Comment: ah ok great. It works!

Comment: anyway to have the file names contain 6 digits like 000001.jpg?

Comment: Yes, adjust the `%4` to `%6` :)